# How to show an activity in front of key guard(with pin locked)

Tags: android, tablet, keyguard

I found Gtalk coming call can show in tablet when tablet is screen off and locked with pin Key guard.

But I don't know why? Any one can help?

add following tag in onCreate(..) function of an activity can do it. But it need the activity is full screen, but how about not full screen?

```
parms.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED; 
parms.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD; 
parms.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON; 
parms.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
```